# Why is authoize.net returning response code Ok I00001 "Successful" however, the customers credit cards are still getting declined?

Tags: php, authorize.net

I have a client that I did an Authorize.net AIM system for. When the transaction goes through, the response contains the result code "Ok", the response code I00001 and response message of "Successful". Sometimes I will also get an authcode back in the response as well, but it will still show declined in the Authorize.net portal. Is this an issue with Authorize.net or am I looking for the wrong things in the response codes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That response means the transaction was completed successfully. It does *not* mean the card is approved.

In other words, Authorize.Net communicated the transaction to the merchant account provider without error and received a proper response. That response may indicate a successful payment was made or the card was declined.

Comment: OK, so I started checking for a 1 in:
transactionResponse -> messages -> message -> code
Would a 1 there signify that the transaction as successful and approved?

Comment: I guess the better question to be asking is, what should I be looking for in the response to verify that the credit card was successfully charged?

Comment: After doing some more reading, I have come to the conclusion that I need to be checking for transactionResponse -> responseCode. Can you please confirm this is correct?

Comment: That is exactly what you should be looking for.